# How do I offer a client the possibility to download a file with Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am building a web application, some sort of a dropbox, where a user can upload any type of file using Spring MVC and Hibernate. I have an input of type "file" for the upload, i have a method in the controller that handles the upload request by taking a multipart file as parameter and storing that file in the database for the specific user. The problem is that I have no idea how to hand over the file back to the client. After I retrieve the file from the data base, how do I return it and what should I have on the front-end in order for a window to pup up and ask for a download path? Or tell me where can I read about this.

Thanks

Comment: Also, I use tymeleaf as a template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourURL/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void download(HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...Find your file to download
    File file = //retrieve your file
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
    if (mimeType == null) {
        logger.debug("mimetype is not detectable, will take default");
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    try {
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName()));
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("An exception has occurred trying to download the file", ex);
    }
}
```

1. Create a URL to identify which document want the user to download, maybe you need add some parameters or path variables
2. Find the file from the DB and build the File object and determine the mimeType
3. Add to the response the file, and according to the browser the user is using the file will be automatically downloaded or will ask for download it
4. In your JSP/HTML files you only need create a button/link with the href of this URL.

Comment: So the download window is open by the browser automatically when the server response contains a file?

Comment: @BobernacAlexandru yeap, because you add it to the HttpServletResponse and is the normal behaviour of the browser

Comment: @BobernacAlexandru did you try it? is working for you now?

Comment: It works! I had some problems with converting the bytes that I took from the database but it finally worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BobernacAlexandru thats great :)